# How can i pick a particular text from a html page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

```
<a href="http://192.168.1.218/idea/abc/coding.aspx">This page contains code.</a>

<a href="..................../idea/xyz/title.aspx">This is the Title Page.</a>

<a href="..................../idea/jkl/head.aspx">Nothing to do with this.</a>
```

In results i want abc, xyz, jkl only.

What will be the regular expressions or code for the same...?

Comment: See [What is the best way to parse html in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/56107/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-c)

Comment: can you post any code over here?

Comment: WebClient web = new WebClient();


            string html = web.DownloadString("http://192.168.1.218.com/");

            MatchCollection mc = Regex.Matches(html, @"href=[']([^']+?)[']", RegexOptions.Multiline);

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
var bits = Regex
    .Matches(html, @"/idea/(.*?)/.*?.aspx\"">")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(m => m.Groups[1]);
```

But don't do this unless you know what you're doing - Use the [HTML Agility Pack](https://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/), instead